# If Python interpreter executes the code line by line, how is the function definition present in the program before function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've studied that Python interpreter executes the code line by line. If that's the case, how are function definitions present before the function calls in Python?

If my understanding is correct, when the Python interpreter encounters a function call, it looks for the appropriate function definition and executes the definition. If that's the case, how does the Python interpreter execute the below code?

```py
def hello( mylist ):    
   print ("Values inside the function before change: ", mylist)     
   mylist[1]=11         
   print ("Values inside the function after change: ", mylist)       
   return     

mylist = [10,12,13]        
hello( mylist )          
print ("Values outside the function: ", mylist)
```

Comment: If Python executes the code line by line (and it does), how could the function definition be present in the program only *after* the function call? When you came to call it, it wouldn't yet be defined (and that's exactly what happens if you move the definition down - you get a `NameError`).

Answer (score 4):

Python is interpreting the code line by line. The first line `def hello( mylist ):` is interpreted and the `hello` function call is added to the `globals` list.

```
print("Before definition: " + str(globals()))

def hello( mylist ):    
   print ("Values inside the function before change: ", mylist)     
   mylist[1]=11         
   print ("Values inside the function after change: ", mylist)       
   return 


print("After definition" + str(globals()))
```

Produces the following output:

```
Before definition: {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': 'blah.py', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
After definition:  {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'blah.py', '__doc__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, 'hello': <function hello at 0x027CAAF0>}
```

Note the function 'hello' appears at the end of the printed dictionary after the `hello` function has been defined. However, the code in the function has not been executed because it has not been called yet.

The code in the function is only executed one you call `hello( mylist )`.

This means that you cannot call a function until it has been defined. For example, putting the call to `hello` above the function definition gives a name error:

```
>>> NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```